# should there be space between a sentence and question mark or not?

Tags: question-mark, spacing

while asking questions in the sentence do we need to give space between question mark **(?)** and the sentence.

what is your name?

what is your name ?

**which one is correct?**

Comment: In English there is no space. Other European languages prefer the space, but of the approximately eleventy billion sentences I've read in English, ***none of them*** separate the final word and the question mark (or exclamation mark) with a space. I only ever see that from non-native speakers online.

Comment: To elaborate on what Robusto said, by "other European languages" he really meant "exactly one European language".

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I didn't want to point fingers.

Comment: @Robusto neither did I. Which is why I never even mentioned the French.